# PIP says python-magic is installed, but substanced says it is not

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6, python-magic

I'm followin the Substanced installation instructions here http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/substanced/en/latest/install.html

step:3 `$ bin/python -c "from substanced.file import magic; assert magic is not None, 'python-magic not installed'"` => `python-magic not installed`

So I run `pip install python-magic` => `Requirement already satisfied: python-magic in c:\users\edmunds\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages`

Any ideas why I'm getting mixed messages here?

Comment: My guess you've got multiple installations of python.  You appear to be specifying `bin/python` and not relying on $PATH, but when you run `pip, you seem to leave it to `$PATH` to find pip.  This is likely why you're getting inconsistent results.  Hint: docker provides great runtime isolation and I run all my nontrivial python in a docker these days do avoid such headaches.

Comment: I've uninstallled 2.7 prior 3.6 installation. Following your suggestion I run an instrallation on virtual environment. Same result :(

Comment: Have you tried Docker yet?  Highly recommended.  Sometimes python programs can escape their virtualenv ( this can be a stubborn problem with ansible, which is imho pretty badly engineered, but I've seen it with other things too ).  Docker solves it by dedicating a whole ( slimmed ) userspace.

Comment: I've spent few hours trying to learn it on youtube. I'm gonna try it to day, think it might open a whole new world to me :)